# How get model from Collection by id?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Help me.
How get model from Collection by id?

```
var Sidebar = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var sidebar = new Sidebar;
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({})
lib=new Library();

lib.add(sidebar,{at: 234});

console.log(lib.get(234))//undefined ..Why??
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be mixing `id` and `index`, which aren't interchangeable.

To retrieve by `id`, you'll want to set it with the `Model`:

```
var sidebar = new Sidebar({ id: 234 });

// ...

console.log(lib.get(234));
```

The `index` is the placement within the collection:

```
lib.add(sidebar, { at: 0 });

console.log(lib.at(0));     // sidebar
console.log(lib.models);    // Array: [ sidebar ]
console.log(lib.models[0]); // sidebar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var Sidebar = Backbone.Model.extend({
     // Need to set this. Otherwise the model
     // does not know what propert is it's id
     idAttribute : 'at'
});
var sidebar = new Sidebar();
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({})
var lib=new Library();

// Set the Model
sidebar.set({at:234});

// Add it to the collection
lib.add(sidebar);

console.log(lib.get(234))
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/2QTdn/)**

The way you were adding the collection `will be spliced at that index` and the model inserted at that index. I don't think that is not what you want. So you need to set the attributes to the model first and then add it to the collection.